# Marker pin disappears in webview Android?

Tags: webview, cordova, android-webview, leaflet

I'm creating a map app. I'm using leafletJS inside a webview in android. The functionally is great, except from the blue marker which should be om my map. In a PhoneGap application my marker shows, as well in a browser. But not inside a android webview. The small shadow that belongs to the marker shows. But not the pin. See screenhot: https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5193cd574768e0d07e000189/519699303ef843e86500742e/08e7b43f12c3e6d1ffcf02f8ba6919c6/Screenshot_2013-05-15-22-28-47-1.png

How come?

See code:

http://pastebin.com/EJXz9Run (index.html)
http://pastebin.com/JGXjTmz4 (js/leaflet.js)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the marker icon is missing. Download leaflet maps from here: http://leafletjs.com/download.html and be sure that you use /dist/images/marker-icon.png

Comment: The thing is that I've downloaded this marker, change path for  it and placed it inside a folder. This works in my browser, but NOT inside a PhoneGap application.

Comment: pastebin says "Unknown Paste ID!". Could you repost your code?
Also, for me it works fine when I put it in \www\dist\images in phonegap project.